# Way to control height and border bottom flex child

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to control border bottom of flex-child 2 only. 
So if I give display: flex to parent and border to both the childs, border will remain same for both depending on the height of any child div.

I don't want to increase height(border bottom) of child 2 as child 1 but I want it to have height as it's content only.

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.two {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
      Testing One<br> Testing One<br> Testing One<br> Testing One
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      Testing Two
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is it really possible using flexbox

Comment: It's possible. Just add `align-items: flex-start;` to your flex container (default value is `align-items: stretch`, which stretches all items to the height of the tallest one).

Comment: @iilya, working, thanks. Please answer so that I can close this thread.